# Horizontally centre '::before' item and other div element with flex concept in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

```css
.status-light-red::before{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}

.status-light::before{
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row job-list-view-section">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
            <div>
               <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Company Name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Applied Job For</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>status</p>
            </div>
            <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using here bootstrap 4.3.1 with flex concept with some custom pieces of CSS. Here the **status-light** and other div items are not proper center horizontally, how am I doing center horizontally?

Note: Don't want a solution by adding custom top property value (Ex. top:58%; or top:58px;), I need a proper logical solution.

Comment: BTW, [you don't need vendor prefixes for box-shadow](https://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding from `<p>`.

Also, to align the red dot add `top: calc(50% - 5px);` to `::before`.

See [MDN calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).

```css
.status-light-red::before{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}

.status-light::before{
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.job-list-view-section p{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row job-list-view-section">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
            <div>
               <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Company Name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Applied Job For</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>status</p>
            </div>
            <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

also, you could try displaying the parent flex like

```css
.status-light-red::before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}
.status-light{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.status-light::before{
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*top pos removed*/
}

.job-list-view-section p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row job-list-view-section">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
        <div>
          <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Company Name</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Applied Job For</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>status</p>
        </div>
        <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sarout, thank you for giving an answer, but your solution is not working, actually, there is no padding put in the p tag. consider the default padding or margin.

Comment: Ok then you need to align the red dot, I edit the question, can u check?

Comment: I know by using MDN calculator or custom value it should fix but it, not the proper way for a responsive purpose, It will fix if add top:35px; but I need a logical responsive solution.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, but also you suppose to say what you've tried, I'll find it for you

Comment: @DevWebTK check the edit please, *I think* this is the **proper** one

Comment: Ok, this could be proper but I find the perfect one from the last comment from you, the solution is to add two classes in the status-light div which is  'd-flex' and 'align-item-center'. You just write a CSS version of it. BTW Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241473/discussion-between-devwebtk-and-sarout).

Answer (score 1):

You might use vertical translation to bring it up in line with the text elements. Notice that I stripped out the span and paragraph elements which don't seem to be doing anything.

```css
.status-light-red::before{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}

.status-light::before{
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row job-list-view-section">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>Company Name</div>
            <div>Job Applied For</div>
            <div>Status</div>
            <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the p the same line-height as the container  - here I added some borders and padding just to be painfully obvious what is where.
I also made some p into a div because that seems "cleaner" given your requirement.

```css
.job-list-view-section {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.job-list-view-section .col-12 {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.job-list-view-section .col-12 .d-flex {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.job-list-view-section .col-12 .my-shadow>* {
  border: 1px green solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:3rem;
}

.job-list-view-section .col-12 .my-shadow>*>p {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-start;
  line-height: 2.9rem;  /*match to align text in the p to the green box, less than 3 for the borders */
}

.wrap-things {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px lime;
  align-self: center;
}

.status-light {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  height: 0.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
}

.status-light-red::before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}

.status-light::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row job-list-view-section">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
        <div>
          <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>Company Name</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Applied Job For</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>status</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-things">
          <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See, borders:

```css
.status-light-red::before{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 75%);
}

.status-light::before{
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top:50%;
}

.my-shadow >div{border: solid 1px red;}
.my-shadow >div>p{border: solid 1px lime;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row job-list-view-section">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark my-shadow p-4">
            <div>
               <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Company Name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Applied Job For</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>status</p>
            </div>
            <div class="status-light status-light-red"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the solution,  the solution is to add two classes in the status-light div which are 'd-flex' and 'align-item-center'.

Comment: @DevWebTK - the other part of this is a paragraph `<p>` has built in spacing (margins) which to center vertically you need to set a fixed line spacing, make it NOT a p by some css adjustments - but why not just make it a div and let the flexbox markup handle the block level element.
Do this: on your ORIGINAL put borders around the <`div>` just inside the .my-shadow element; and the p - you will see the p vertical challenge - the rest are "ok"

Comment: I Added a second hidden sample so you can see the borders on your original to show that the paragraphs are the issue.

Comment: Okay, Get your point.